# Eclipse 202003 javaIO error during build project

Tags: java, eclipse

Has anyone encountered with the following error during use Eclipse latest version: 202003?
I've downloaded it, update Java 1.8 to the latest Java version, start eclipse, add my PHP project and during the building or validation or DLTK indexing I got an Internal error.
Part from eclipse .log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.lucene 1 1 2020-04-30 16:33:01.599
!MESSAGE Recovering index storage: Y:\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.lucene\index\4b74b979-df85-4fb0-bd11-ad91f89ae355\timestamps

!ENTRY org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.lucene 4 4 2020-04-30 16:33:01.617
!MESSAGE Index writer could not be created, index data might be corrupted.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: The request is not supported
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:126)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SleepingLockWrapper.obtainLock(SleepingLockWrapper.java:84)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexContainer.createWriter(IndexContainer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexContainer.getWriter(IndexContainer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexContainer.getTimestampsWriter(IndexContainer.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexRecovery.tryRecover(IndexRecovery.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexContainer.getWriter(IndexContainer.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexContainer.getTimestampsWriter(IndexContainer.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexRecovery.tryRecover(IndexRecovery.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexContainer.getWriter(IndexContainer.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.lucene.IndexContainer.getTimestampsWriter(IndexContainer.java:167)
 ........
```

I've no idea what is going wrong? WTF?
Java version is: jre1.8.0_251 and I've also tried reinstall previous java version what I used. This was: 1.8.0_202...but I got the same error again, and again, and again :(
I would like upgrade my Eclipse because of Symfony plugin...

Previous used java version: 1.8.0_191. I've reinstalled it and got back the error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Build Modules".
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Building process stop at 49% :(
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is `Y:` a local disk, or a network share?

Comment: [This is the Java bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193594) @nitind is talking about. The solution in your case is to choose a different location for your Eclipse workspace than the network share. @ nitind, Do you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: Hi! Y:\ is a NFS shared driver. I am using CentOS on VBox. But everything has worked before I upgrade eclipse. An if I try to use again the previous Eclipse (201906) I have the same problem. :( However, thanks your comment guys :)

Comment: I am getting sure that the problem is with Eclipse latest 202030 (4.15) version. I have downloaded the the previous version of Eclipse 201912 (4.14), set in ini file where to find javaw.exe file (listen to not use space in path!), cleanup my workspace (remove all eclipse spec. setting file like .metadata folder) the start eclipse with -clean flag. It looks like that s working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is problem with DLTK 6.1 + PDT 7.1. We already fixed this: no more async and FS locks. Please update to recent snapshots or try Eclipse 2020-06 M2 or newest: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06/m2